# Is this possible to set the max row size in Hsqldb?

Tags: java, hsqldb

Is this possible to set the max row size in Hsqldb?

In SQL Server 2016, the [limit is 8060](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server). I would like to define the same value in Hsqldb.

The reason for that is our big queries generated by an application that uses a lof of EAGER fetching from Hibernate (bad practice, I know). This results in queries with a lot of rows from different joined tables.

Looking in Hsqldb [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDatabaseMetaData.html#getMaxRowSize--), I found a method `getMaxRowSize`, but seems that is not possible to define the value:

> HSQLDB does not impose a "known" limit. The limit is subject to memory
>   and disk availability; this method **always** returns 0.

This is not very good for me. But I'm thinking if this could be possible in another way or through a "hidden" feature.

Comment: Why not keep the sum of all columns in your ddl below the wanted limit ?

Comment: The problem that I'm trying to address is: in big (really big) queries the SQL Server show an error for me `Cannot create a row of size 8575 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.`. When I run the same query in Hsqldb the same kind of error not occur. So I'm trying to put the same limit in both databases

Comment: Just for my understanding: why do you need to simulate this problem on hsqldb ?

Comment: The application use SQL Server in production/homolog/test environment and Hsqldb is used for development and integration/functional tests. It would be very good if the tests could get this kind of problem.

Comment: Ok, I see. I can't answer your question but you could consider using a "real" SQL server in the shape of a separate developer DB, the developer edition or even a docket image: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/21/sql-server-2016-developer-edition-in-windows-containers/

Comment: It's a nice tip, thank you! I will read more about this solution and how this could fit in our tests. The article mention Windows as host, but we are using Linux, but I can't see why this could't work in Linux too.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to set limits on each character or binary column to ensure the total for a row does not exceed the maximum row size of SQL Server. These limits are enforced both by SQL Server and HSQLDB.

Comment: Hi! I updated my question to bring more information. This limit helps when you are doing big queries with a lot of columns from different joined tables. Limiting the columns in a single table would not help in our scenario.